# Spring: FactoryBean vs @Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am failing to see the utility of FactoryBean for creating a bean...Why coudn't you create the respective bean in an Configuration class? What need is there for the FactoryBean ?

I know I'm missing something here but I can't figure out what exactly

Comment: ??? a FactoryBean is a rather low level  interface for a kind of proxy: you ask for the FactoryBean and actually use its `getObject()`. Why do you want to use `@Configuration` for that?

Comment: I do not think that I deserve a down vote...like I said I am missing something here and that's why I use this site to become better

Comment: This is how I understand things right now: the FactoryBean encapsulates a bean's construction...which to me it seems that it is the exact thing that @Configuration classes are used for. What am i missing here?

Comment: I did not DV. But this is way too broad to expect an answer here. You'd better google around: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/how-to-create-beans-using-spring-factorybean/ , https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean , https://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean , ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Configuration and FactoryBean classes have something similar but Configuration has not only option to produce beans for container. 
@Configuration was created to implement in java everything that was possible to do in xml and even more.

With FactoryBean you can:
1. Create beans using some custom logic
And that is all.
Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html

With Configuration you can:
1. Declare beans without any creational logic.
2. Create beans for container using custom logic(the same as FactoryBean).
3. Declare static beans(see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-value-annotations)
4. Declare @ComponentScan
5. Declare @PropertySource
6. Import another configuration from java config using @Import
7. Import another configuration from xml using @ImportResource
8. Configuration class may be imported for testing usages(as test config)
....a lot of other usages
Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

And the most significant difference is that @Configuration class is managed by Spring container and all its public methods are proxied. 
FactoryBean is not managed by Spring container, it is just a tool to create beans for container.

> NB: A bean that implements this interface cannot be used as a normal bean. A FactoryBean is defined in a bean style, but the object exposed for bean references (getObject()) is always the object that it creates.....FactoryBean is a programmatic contract. Implementations are not supposed to rely on annotation-driven injection or other reflective facilities.

Comment: So why would one use a `FactoryBean` instead of creating the bean in a `@Configuration` class?